# Is there a function f(z) that satisfies a duality relation?

Tags: functions

Is there a function f(z) that satisfies the following duality relation?

$$tf(x)[(1+x)^2-f^2(t)(1-x)^2]=xf(t)[(1+t)^2-f^2(x)(1-t)^2]\ ?$$

Here $f(z)\neq 0$ and $1$.

Comment: You should include what you have tried so far.

Comment: There are at least two solutions which can be found rather quickly, so what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried it, but there is no progress.

Comment: Perhaps you are overthinking the problem because one solution is practically obvious.

Comment: Here $f(z)\neq 0$ and $1$. Have you found other solutions?

Comment: OK, you excluded $f(z)=0$ and $f(z)=1$ that leaves at least one other solution. Since you are using $z$ does that mean complex functions are allowed?

Comment: I hope that $f(z)$ is a real function not complex function.

Comment: Here is a hint to get you started: What do you know about $f(0)$?

Comment: $f(0)$ can  be arbitrary

Comment: What happens in the equation when you let $x=0$? This gives a clue.

Comment: So. We have $f^2(t)=1$.

Comment: So, can you now find a solution other than $f(z)=0$ or $f(z)=1$?

Comment: Thank you very much. It can only be a constant

Comment: At least it has a constant solution other than the two that are excluded.

Comment: I will leave you with one last hint: Let $c=f(-1)$ and try to find an equation for $f(t)$ in terms of $c$ and $t$.

Comment: Thank you. I have found a solution。

Comment: That's great. Usually one attacks this type of problem by finding the functional value of certain constants such $x=0, 1, -1$ etc to see if that gives you any hints about the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $f(t)\ne0$. Let $f(-1)=c$. Let $x=-1$.

Substituting into the equation gives

\begin{eqnarray}
tf(-1)[(0)^2-f^2(t)(2)^2]&=&-f(t)[(1+t)^2-f^2(-1)(1-t)^2]\\
-4ctf^2(t)&=&-f(t)[(1+t)^2-c^2(1-t)^2]\\
4ctf^2(t)-f(t)[(1+t)^2-c^2(1-t)^2]&=&0\\
4ctf(t)-[(1+t)^2-c^2(1-t)^2]&=&0\\
f(t)&=&\frac{(1+t)^2-c^2(1-t)^2}{4ct}
\end{eqnarray}

Which yields a solution for each $c\ne0$.